# Custom Search Query in Django 1.9; GET requests

Tags: python, django, sqlite, querying

I've been trying to implement a search feature for a blog project, and now that several different implementations from a variety of tutorials have all consistently 404'd, regardless of input, I'm looking for the answer, here.

Here's the one that's the most rudimentary to me, of course in `views.py` :

```
def search(request):
    try:
        q = request.GET['q']
        posts = Post.objects.filter(title__search=q)
        return render_to_response('blog/search_post_list.html', {'object_list': posts, 'q':q})
    except KeyError:
        return render_to_response('blog/search_post_list.html')
```

In `blog/urls.py`:
    url(r'^search', search, name='search'),

There's a template at `/templates/blog/search_post_list.html` which has some code containing `{% for post in object_list %}`, identical to a working template.

So, going to any `localhost:8000/blog/search?q=<search_query_here>` is a Django debug page with a 404.

The reason I've kept the code trivially simple is because I have a feeling that there might be something beyond the code, and I'm hoping someone can tell me where to look in the code for it.

EDIT:
Here's the 404 page:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/blog/search?q=what
Raised by:  django.views.generic.detail.DetailView
No post found matching the query
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Here's the URL for my DetailView, since it was apparently called.

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$',
    DetailView.as_view(
    model=Post,
    )),
```

Comment: What is the full text from the 404 debug page?

Comment: @Alasdair 
`Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/blog/search?q=what
Raised by: django.views.generic.detail.DetailView
No post found matching the query
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.`

Comment: I now realize that I might need to put the url for my DetailView. Adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url `/blog/search/` is being handled by your detail view instead of the search view. You then get a 404, because there is no post with `slug=search`.

You can fix this by moving the search url pattern above the detail pattern.

Comment: I'm still getting an error:  
`NotImplementedError at /blog/search
Full-text search is not implemented for this database backend`

Not even sure what that means.
sqlite3 issue?

Comment: That's a completely different issue. As the error says, you cannot use [`__search`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#search) because the sqlite3 backend does not support it. You could do `Post.objects.filter(title__contains=q)` instead.

Comment: Thanks. 
Do you know of a good resource for learning a general picture of the types of querying supported by different databases?
Furthermore, I attempted to do `posts +=` with a different query, hoping the result could be an ordered list, where some fields are placed higher than others, but the operation is not supported. So, I'm hoping the resource will contain information that would help this.

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/) should say if a method is only supported by certain backends. In your code `posts` is a queryset so you can't add items to it. You could convert it to a list first, with `posts = lists(posts)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add url-pattern this way:

```
url(r'search/',
    DetailView.as_view(
    model=Post,
    )),
```

(or 'blog/search/')
With GET request parameters will add like ***/search/?parameter_name1=value1&parameter_name2=value2